# Regexp in Java, how i can parse this string?

Tags: android, regex

I should parse a string like this:

```
Small Intestine (T N M - Stage 0)
```

what I want to save is all the stuff before the first bracket, but I don't know if i'll have one, two ore more strings.

How can I do this in java ? What is the correctly regexp that I must use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExpTest
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){

```
  // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
  String line = "Small Intestine (T N M - Stage 0)";
  String pattern = "^.+?(?= *\\()";


  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " +  m.group(0));

  } else {
     System.out.println("NO MATCH");
  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^.+?(?= *\()
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xP6fB2/1)

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.